# Initializing wonky characters in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm trying to use some funky characters in my Java code.

```
    Character c = new Character('');
```

(If your web browser doesn't display the character, it's "1F000  MAHJONG TILE EAST WIND", as taken from [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F000.pdf).

Java complains about 'invalid character constant'. What gives? I thought Java's Character supported Unicode.

Also, is there a way to initialize a Character by its Unicode value? Something like `new Character('0x01F000')`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will affect what you're doing, but note that Java 6 was written to Unicode 4. _Some_ methods will treat U+1F000 as an undefined code point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-BMP (basic multilingual plane) characters can't be represented as a Java `char` (or thus a `Character`), because a `char` is only a 16-bit unsigned integer. Non-BMP characters are represented using *surrogate pairs* in Java.

You'll need to use a string... but even then I suspect you'll need to provide the surrogate pair of characters explicitly. C# has a `\U` escape sequence which is the equivalent of `\u` but for 32-bit values, but Java doesn't have anything like that :(

Here's an alternative approach which lets you use the Unicode value directly in your code:

```
String x = new String(new int[] { 0x1f000 }, 0, 1);
```

It's ugly, but it works...

Comment: @Jon - you are correct, Java doesn't support `\U`: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.1

Comment: @McDowell: Thanks. Will remove the element of doubt from the answer :)

Comment: Ehm. Java String literals do allow for `\u` escaping so this character would simply be `String s = "\u1f000";` What's I believe that really is going on here is that since that particular character is in Unicode 6.0 code page, it's not supported by Java since Unicode 6.0 support will be added in JDK7.

Comment: @Esko: no it has nothing to do with Unicode 6.0.  Java starting showing its shortsighted 16-bits *char* SNAFU as soon as Unicode 3.1 came out.  The \u construct was as poorly thought as *char*: it needs exactly four hexdigits following '\u' and that's it.  Try to encode a musical note from outside the BMP using \uxxxx: they exist since Unicode 3.1 and you cannot encode them using \uxxxx.  To me it's not at all related to Unicode 6.0.  The issue is much older than that.

Comment: @Esko - some languages use the upper case escape `\U` sequences for code points outside the BMP - see here for examples: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html Java only supports the lower case `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits.

Comment: @Esko: No, "\u1f000" is two characters: U+1F00 and '0'. Try it!

Comment: @Jon: I actually thought about this for a bit longer after posting (*and realizing that I'm mostly wrong*), Java as a language has problems in these cases in general since it tries hard to be a generic in all things while IO etc. is always quite system specific. C# is supposed to be more C++ like than Java like which means that these sort of things won't occur in C# just as easily as in Java. To others: Points taken, I need to read more on this.

Comment: @Esko: No, I disagree strongly. In terms of string and character handling, C# is *much* more like Java. (I'd argue that *in general* C# is more like Java than C++ as well, but particularly for string handling.) In both cases, strings are based on UTF-16 characters, and the primitive char type is only 16-bit. The only way in which C# makes this easier is by having the "\U" escape sequence, which Java *could* easily have had. C# had the benefit of coming later, when there *were* non-BMP characters, that's all.

Comment: @Jon: I think we need to agree to disagree here, then. I've found more logical parallels between C# and C++ than with Java but that may be just a matter of taste. In any case, being a Finn I've had to deal with charsets ever since I first time typed a simple greeting to some old beans newsgroup/IRC... anyways, I think I just do think of the semantics a bit differently when it comes to charsets than a lot of other people, mostly because for the past year I've had to fight a lot of weird stuff related to them because of my work. Good example of this would be Greek capitalization... :)

Comment: @Jon: I do also agree that C# had the benefit of coming later (*and thus naturally making its own mistakes*), I just seem to be in the mood of writing huge walls of text today.

Comment: @Esko: Gah - I've just lost a long comment on C++/Java/C#. Bearing in mind the object model, type hierarchy, memory model (GC etc), compilation model, exceptions, synchronization etc - where do you see C# as being more like C++ than Java? All I can think of offhand is custom value types, operator overloading and pointers.

Comment: @Jon: On top of what you mentioned, the actual internal logic semantics of the language in various places reminds me more of C++ than Java. Then again, there's just about as many ways/styles to write C++ as there are programmer so maybe it's just that.

Comment: @Esko: Which bits of "internal logic semantics" are you talking about? Specific examples would be very handy :)

Comment: @Jon: Hard to explain with my non-native knowledge of English, but I mean the programmatic aspect of tackling issues as part of the overall solution. With this I do mean both actual solution code (*like applying design patterns*) and the way you may think in general (*procedural/functional/OO*)...these sort of things. Sorry I can't really explain it more clearer, my vocabulary is missing some of the relevant big words :)

Comment: @Esko: In those terms, I think C# and Java are *extremely* close... C# encourages a more functional approach than Java these days with the use of lambda expressions, but that's the only significant difference I can think of immediately. I would generally approach the overall problem in Java and C# in a similar way... whereas C++ can suggest very different design patterns, particularly due to the different approach to memory and RAII.

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative, but you can also use:

```
String str = new String(Character.toChars(0x1F000) );
```

Comment: you could also use `String str = "\ud83c\udc00";`, but this obfuscates the code point.

Comment: @mcd You're right of course, but I'd prefer to let the Character class do the heavy lifting of translating into surrogate pairs :)